# different permissions running script from web browser or www-data user

Tags: nginx, permissions, web-server, fastcgi, perl

I want a perl to write to my server's file system but I have a problem.
It fails when checking permissions (with `-w`). I reduced the issue to its simplest expression :

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
print "Content-type:text/html\n\n";

$dir = "/var/www/stock/my/dir";
print $>,"\n"; # UID
if(-w $dir){ print "can write\n" }
else { print "cannot\n" }
```

This is the result when ran with the user `www-data`

```
www-data@hersent:~/stock$ perl test.pl 
Content-type:text/html

33
can write
```

And when accessed [through the web browser](https://stock.ysengr.in:8021/test.pl) :
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iYMKs.png)

I think the only difference is that when ran through the web browser, it involves nginx and fastcgi-wrapper. But they are also running as www-data

```
root@hersent:/var/www/stock# ps aux | grep -E "cgi|nginx"
www-data   474  0.0  0.1  30092  5028 ?        Ss   Feb14   0:00 /usr/bin/perl /usr/bin/fastcgi-wrapper.pl
www-data  5131  0.0  0.0  29596  2496 ?        Ss   Feb24   0:00 /usr/sbin/fcgiwrap -f
root      6324  0.0  0.0  32708   956 ?        Ss   Feb24   0:00 nginx: master process /usr/sbin/nginx -c /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
www-data  6325  0.0  0.1  33320  6316 ?        S    Feb24   0:56 nginx: worker process
```

So I am lost now. What can I do ?
Thank you

Comment: The web server that your web server runs as needs permission to write to that directory.

Comment: @Tim it has ! nginx runs as `www-data` and you can see in my second code snippet that www-data **can** write to that directory

Answer (score 0):

Okay, as @Tim convinced me to do, I set the directory's permissions to 775 (rwxrwxr-x) and the owners to `user:www-data`. It was previously set to `user:user` and `www-data` was in the group `user`.

```
# sudo -u www-data groups
www-data user
```

I might still be missing something in the linux user/group knowledge. What is the point of adding a user to a group if he doesn't benefit from its permissions ?

Comment: 775 are quite wide permissions. I've described how I set up Wordpress permissions [here](https://www.photographerstechsupport.com/tutorials/hosting-wordpress-on-aws-tutorial-part-2-setting-up-aws-for-wordpress-with-rds-nginx-hhvm-php-ssmtp/#fp).

Comment: Hi, I don't have much choice if I several user to be able to write to it. 750 won't do. Please correct me if I'm wrong